# Debian 10 - Bonding interfaces don't provide ip address dmesg error "invalid new link 3 on slave <interface>"

Tags: debian, networking

I'm having an error when bonding interfaces on Debian 10 (Buster).

Here's my bond configuration

```
auto bond0

iface bond0 inet manual
 address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
 netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
 
bond-mode balance-rr
bond-miimon 100
bond-slaves enp9s0 enp10s0
bond-downdelay 200
bond-updelay 200
```

And bellow is how the interfaces are configured:

```
allow-hotplug

iface enp9s0 inet manual
bond-master bond0
bond-mode balance-rr

allow-hotplug

iface enp10s0 inet manual

bond-master bond0
bond-mode balance-rr
```

Here's the output from dmesg.

```
[2416927.202898] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): bond0: link is not ready
[2416929.492175] r8169 0000:09:00.0 enp9s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[2416929.539426] r8169 0000:0a:00.0 enp10s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[2416929.593686] bond0: link status up for interface enp9s0, enabling it in 0 ms
[2416929.593689] bond0: link status up for interface enp10s0, enabling it in 200 ms
[2416929.593733] bond0: link status definitely up for interface enp9s0, 1000 Mbps full duplex
[2416929.593740] bond0: first active interface up!
[2416929.593742] bond0: invalid new link 3 on slave enp10s0
[2416929.594770] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): bond0: link becomes ready
```

Any advices?

Comment: I had a similar issue and in my case the switch from manual to static solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I have two debian 10 systems on a palo alto firewall, and they both get this bonding "**invalid new link 3 on slave**" error, yet are fine per getting online with the bond (i.e. the error is not fatal to me)

I also have other machines that are not on palo firewalls, but they do not get this error

for me, this error is triggered when a nic comes back into the nic team (on a palo firewall attached box)

I found this post because I was curious if it meant something; but wow, there is very very little on the internet as far as your error, so hopefully this at least helps you to know that this error isn't stopping at least one person from being online; so, you may have other troubles that aren't related to this error

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep bond0

[   95.382892] bonding: bond0 is being created...
[   95.432520] bond0: Enslaving eno1 as a backup interface with an up link
[   95.465622] bond0: Enslaving eno2 as a backup interface with an up link
[   95.498994] bond0: Enslaving eno3 as a backup interface with an up link
[   95.508300] bond0: Warning: No 802.3ad response from the link partner for any adapters in the bond
[   95.508354] bond0: link status definitely up for interface eno1, 1000 Mbps full duplex
[   95.508359] bond0: first active interface up!
[   95.529105] bond0: Enslaving eno4 as a backup interface with an up link
[   95.716442] bond0: link status definitely up for interface eno2, 1000 Mbps full duplex
[   95.716477] bond0: link status definitely up for interface eno3, 1000 Mbps full duplex
[   95.820358] bond0: link status definitely up for interface eno4, 1000 Mbps full duplex
[339713.580713] bond0: link status definitely down for interface eno1, disabling it
[339713.580724] bond0: first active interface up!
[339717.976553] bond0: link status up for interface eno1, enabling it in 200 ms
[339717.976558] bond0: invalid new link 3 on slave eno1
[339718.188596] bond0: link status definitely up for interface eno1, 1000 Mbps full duplex
[425443.657516] bond0: link status definitely down for interface eno2, disabling it
[425443.657525] bond0: first active interface up!
[425450.177244] bond0: link status up for interface eno2, enabling it in 200 ms
[425450.177254] bond0: invalid new link 3 on slave eno2
[425450.385317] bond0: link status definitely up for interface eno2, 1000 Mbps full duplex
```

Comment: I'm getting the error too and just like it is the case for @hunter3740 the bond interface actually works and transmits packets.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me , debian 10 .

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# onboard network interface I217
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet manual

# onboard network interface I210
auto eno2
iface eno2 inet manual

#bond inteface
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet manual
        bond_slaves eno1 eno2
        bond_mode 4
        mtu 9000

# bridge interface
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        bridge_ports bond0
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_waitport 20
        bridge_stp on
        address 10.10.10.20
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 10.10.10.0
        broadcast 10.10.10.255
        gateway 10.10.10.254
```

Comment: Please do not slap configuration files without explaining them. For starters, mtu 9000 should not be (ab)used in most situations.